# While installing vollib package in python, I got an error as follows: Command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7

Tried to install Swig for Windows separately. But the same problem persists.

[image]

Comment: what screen shot?

Comment: This is the error message that was shown in Command Prompt when I used pip install vollib command. swig.exe command is not recognized while the prerequisites are being installed.